# How do i intercept an URL with a pathvariable using Regex?

Tags: regex, angular, typescript

I have an interceptor in my angular app where a loading spinner is disabled on specific GET requests. Until now i had no trouble until i had to add an URL with a path variable. I don't know how to capture the path variable with Regex. Here are the essential code snippets:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoadingScreenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    let displayLoadingScreen = true;

    for (const skippUrl of this.skippUrls) {
      if (new RegExp(skippUrl).test(request.url)) {
        displayLoadingScreen = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    ...
```

The urls that have to be skipped:

```
  skippUrls = [ 
    '/product/images',
    '/product/${productId}/image', // Stuck on this one. Simply copy pasting the url string doesn't seem to work
    '/category/', 
    ...
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You will have to expand the path variable before testing. Regex is probably overkill here. Doing a case independent string comparison may suffice. Using a regex in that style may lead to more problems if skipurls contains other regex special symbols.

Comment: @AdrianHHH The application is fully written at this point and is not going to get extended. i just had to do some optimizations. But it's not a bad idea, i'll look for a refactor tomorrow. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
'\/product\/.*\/(image)$'
```